# bounding data to mschart so i can return non-data point-values

Tags: vb.net, mschart, stacked-chart

I'm trying to build a chart composed of up-to-100% stacked columns, each with 4 series and, once built, upon hovering upon the series, return all bound data (in this case, user names)

I'm very close to what i want, but the tooltip is showing only the sums, which is expected, but i dont know how to proceed. If there's another way that passes over the hover, like clicking and, in the click, I recognize the series and all those that are there, that would help immensely too

[What I Have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTi8f.png)

[What I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6knd.png)

After looking it up, i built the chart this way:
(right now its a code nightmare, but i will methodify everything properly later)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


Dim sql As New SqlCommand(my query, my connector)
connect()
Dim rs = sql.ExecuteReader
Dim dtTest1 As DataTable = New DataTable
If rs.Read Then
   dtTest1.Load(rs)
End If
disconnect()

    Dim arrayTempoCallback(dtTest1.Rows.Count) As Double
    Dim arrayTempoInaptidao(dtTest1.Rows.Count) As Double
    Dim arrayTempoParabens(dtTest1.Rows.Count) As Double
    Dim arrayTempoRecusa(dtTest1.Rows.Count) As Double
    Dim arrayTempoSemDados(dtTest1.Rows.Count) As Double

    For Each item In dtTest1.Rows
        arrayTempoCallback(dtTest1.Rows.IndexOf(item)) = item("TEMPO_CALLBACK")
        arrayTempoInaptidao(dtTest1.Rows.IndexOf(item)) = item("TEMPO_INAPTIDAO")
        arrayTempoParabens(dtTest1.Rows.IndexOf(item)) = item("TEMPO_PARABENS")
        arrayTempoRecusa(dtTest1.Rows.IndexOf(item)) = item("TEMPO_RECUSA")
        arrayTempoSemDados(dtTest1.Rows.IndexOf(item)) = item("TEMPO_SEMDADOS")
    Next

    Dim QuartisCallBack = Quartiles(arrayTempoCallback)
    Dim QuartisTempoInaptidao = Quartiles(arrayTempoInaptidao)
    Dim QuartisTempoParabens = Quartiles(arrayTempoParabens)
    Dim QuartisTempoRecusa = Quartiles(arrayTempoRecusa)
    Dim QuartisTempoSemDados = Quartiles(arrayTempoSemDados)

    Dim tabelafinal As New DataTable
    tabelafinal.Columns.Add("VALORES", GetType(String))
    tabelafinal.Columns.Add("COLUNA", GetType(String))
    tabelafinal.Columns.Add("COR", GetType(String))
    Dim somaS As Integer = 0
    Dim somaH As Integer = 0
    Dim somaC As Integer = 0
    Dim somaD As Integer = 0

    For Each linha In dtTest1.Rows
        If linha("TEMPO_INAPTIDAO") < QuartisTempoInaptidao.Item1 Then
            somaS += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_INAPTIDAO") >= QuartisTempoInaptidao.Item1 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_INAPTIDAO") < QuartisTempoInaptidao.Item2 Then
            somaH += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_INAPTIDAO") >= QuartisTempoInaptidao.Item2 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_INAPTIDAO") < QuartisTempoInaptidao.Item3 Then
            somaC += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_INAPTIDAO") >= QuartisTempoInaptidao.Item3 Then
            somaD += 1
        End If
    Next

    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaS, "TM_INAP", "D")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaH, "TM_INAP", "C")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaC, "TM_INAP", "H")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaD, "TM_INAP", "S")
    somaC = somaD = somaH = somaS = 0

    For Each linha In dtTest1.Rows
        If linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") < QuartisTempoParabens.Item1 Then
            somaS += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") >= QuartisTempoParabens.Item1 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") < QuartisTempoParabens.Item2 Then
            somaH += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") >= QuartisTempoParabens.Item2 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") < QuartisTempoParabens.Item3 Then
            somaC += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") >= QuartisTempoParabens.Item3 Then
            somaD += 1
        End If
    Next

    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaS, "TM_PARABENS", "S")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaH, "TM_PARABENS", "H")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaC, "TM_PARABENS", "C")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaD, "TM_PARABENS", "D")
    somaC = somaD = somaH = somaS = 0

    For Each linha In dtTest1.Rows
        If linha("TEMPO_RECUSA") < QuartisTempoRecusa.Item1 Then
            somaS += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_RECUSA") >= QuartisTempoRecusa.Item1 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") < QuartisTempoRecusa.Item2 Then
            somaH += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_RECUSA") >= QuartisTempoRecusa.Item2 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") < QuartisTempoRecusa.Item3 Then
            somaC += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_RECUSA") >= QuartisTempoRecusa.Item3 Then
            somaD += 1
        End If
    Next

    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaS, "TM_RECUSA", "S")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaH, "TM_RECUSA", "H")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaC, "TM_RECUSA", "C")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaD, "TM_RECUSA", "D")

    somaC = somaD = somaH = somaS = 0

    For Each linha In dtTest1.Rows
        If linha("TEMPO_SEMDADOS") < QuartisTempoSemDados.Item1 Then
            somaS += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_SEMDADOS") >= QuartisTempoSemDados.Item1 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") < QuartisTempoSemDados.Item2 Then
            somaH += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_SEMDADOS") >= QuartisTempoSemDados.Item2 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") < QuartisTempoSemDados.Item3 Then
            somaC += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_SEMDADOS") >= QuartisTempoSemDados.Item3 Then
            somaD += 1
        End If
    Next
    Dim somaFinalSemDadosS As Integer = If(somaS < 0, 0, somaS)
    Dim somaFinalSemDadosH As Integer = If(somaH < 0, 0, somaH)
    Dim somaFinalSemDadosC As Integer = If(somaC < 0, 0, somaC)
    Dim somaFinalSemDadosD As Integer = If(somaD < 0, 0, somaD)

    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaFinalSemDadosS, "TM_SEMDADOS", "S")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaFinalSemDadosH, "TM_SEMDADOS", "H")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaFinalSemDadosC, "TM_SEMDADOS", "C")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaFinalSemDadosD, "TM_SEMDADOS", "D")

    somaC = somaD = somaH = somaS = 0

    For Each linha In dtTest1.Rows
        If linha("TEMPO_CALLBACK") < QuartisCallBack.Item1 Then
            somaS += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_CALLBACK") >= QuartisCallBack.Item1 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") < QuartisCallBack.Item2 Then
            somaH += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_CALLBACK") >= QuartisCallBack.Item2 AndAlso linha("TEMPO_PARABENS") < QuartisCallBack.Item3 Then
            somaC += 1
        ElseIf linha("TEMPO_CALLBACK") >= QuartisCallBack.Item3 Then
            somaD += 1
        End If
    Next
    Dim somaFinalCallBackS As Integer = If(somaS < 0, 0, somaS)
    Dim somaFinalCallBackH As Integer = If(somaH < 0, 0, somaH)
    Dim somaFinalCallBackC As Integer = If(somaC < 0, 0, somaC)
    Dim somaFinalCallBackD As Integer = If(somaD < 0, 0, somaD)

    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaFinalCallBackS, "TEMPO_CALLBACK", "S")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaFinalCallBackH, "TEMPO_CALLBACK", "H")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaFinalCallBackC, "TEMPO_CALLBACK", "C")
    tabelafinal.Rows.Add(somaFinalCallBackD, "TEMPO_CALLBACK", "D")

    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(tabelafinal)

    Chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel()
    Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dv, "COR", "COLUNA", "VALORES", "")

    For Each cs As Series In Chart1.Series
        cs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn100
        cs.ToolTip = "Pessoas = #VALY"
    Next
End Sub

Friend Function Quartiles(ByVal afVal As Double()) As Tuple(Of Double, Double, Double)
    Dim iSize As Integer = afVal.Length
    System.Array.Sort(afVal)
    Dim iMid As Integer = iSize / 2
    Dim fQ1 As Double = 0
    Dim fQ2 As Double = 0
    Dim fQ3 As Double = 0

    If iSize Mod 2 = 0 Then
        fQ2 = (afVal(iMid - 1) + afVal(iMid)) / 2
        Dim iMidMid As Integer = iMid / 2

        If iMid Mod 2 = 0 Then
            fQ1 = (afVal(iMidMid - 1) + afVal(iMidMid)) / 2
            fQ3 = (afVal(iMid + iMidMid - 1) + afVal(iMid + iMidMid)) / 2
        Else
            fQ1 = afVal(iMidMid)
            fQ3 = afVal(iMidMid + iMid)
        End If
    ElseIf iSize = 1 Then
        fQ1 = afVal(0)
        fQ2 = afVal(0)
        fQ3 = afVal(0)
    Else
        fQ2 = afVal(iMid)

        If (iSize - 1) Mod 4 = 0 Then
            Dim n As Integer = (iSize - 1) / 4
            fQ1 = (afVal(n - 1) * 0.25) + (afVal(n) * 0.75)
            fQ3 = (afVal(3 * n) * 0.75) + (afVal(3 * n + 1) * 0.25)
        ElseIf (iSize - 3) Mod 4 = 0 Then
            Dim n As Integer = (iSize - 3) / 4
            fQ1 = (afVal(n) * 0.75) + (afVal(n + 1) * 0.25)
            fQ3 = (afVal(3 * n + 1) * 0.25) + (afVal(3 * n + 2) * 0.75)
        End If
    End If

    Return New Tuple(Of Double, Double, Double)(fQ1, fQ2, fQ3)
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to show a tooltip (when hovering the cursor over one colored 'block' in the chart) that shows information about the data that makes up the point.

The problem is that each 'block' is only a single X and Y value. For example: The DataPoint behind the tooltip that shows 'Pessoas = 392' is actually just a simple DataPoint (Series-S X=5 Y=392) with no additional information.

To show a tooltip the way you want each one will have to be pre-set, like this:

```
point.ToolTip = "User1 in the series\nUser2 in the series\n..."
```

Comment: Nice, it worked. Now the tooltip i'm using is insanely tall, but thats another can of worms entirely. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @pedro-nassetti if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56824274/2509042) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.